# "Tools > XML Actions" Menu option missing from Intellij Idea

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

I have tried to generate XSD schema from XML file as per described in below article.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-xml-schema-from-instance-document.html

But in my Intellij Idea installation there is no menu option called "XML Actions" in Tools menu. Does anyone know how to enable that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. You need to open the XSD file in the editor window to enable that menu item.